# Fit two div's inside a variable width parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a long div that holds 4 elements in the following order:

```
icon       (fixed width)
item_name  [needs to fit inside]
item_type  [needs to fit inside]
item_date  (fixed width)
```

I am trying to figure out how to fit the `item_name` and `item_type` inside so that they always fit inside the div regardless of resize.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qpyv6en/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></div> 
    <div class="item_date">7:25 AM</div>
    <div style="border-top:1px solid green;width:500px;">
        <div class="item_name">Item name</div>
        <div class="item_type">Item type</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:80%;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #e5e5e5, 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
}
.item .icon {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:75px;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid blue;
    font-size:23px;
    color:#252525;
    line-height:50px;
}
.item .item_date {
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:100px;
    border-top:1px solid blue;
    height:50px;
    padding:0 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#999999;
    line-height:50px;
}
.item .item_name {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border-top:1px solid purple;
}
.item .item_type {
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top:1px solid yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `overflow: auto` to the `div.item-panel` element that contains the two floated blocks.  Setting `overflow: auto` defines a block-formatting context and the floats are contained within the edges of the block, which is what you need in this case.

```css
.item {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:80%;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #e5e5e5, 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
}
.item .icon {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:75px;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid blue;
    font-size:23px;
    color:#252525;
    line-height:50px;
}
.item .item_date {
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:100px;
    border-top:1px solid blue;
    height:50px;
    padding:0 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#999999;
    line-height:50px;
}
.item-panel {
    border-top: 5px solid green;
    overflow: auto;
}
.item .item_name {
    float:left;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border-top:1px solid purple;
}
.item .item_type {
    float:right;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top:1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="icon">X</div>
    <div class="item_date">7:25 AM</div>
    <div class="item-panel">
        <div class="item_name">First</div>
        <div class="item_type">Second</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc! This work's perfectly. I can't figure out what you did. Could you explain what's different here then mine?

Comment: First, I added a class `.item-panel` to clean up the inline CSS.  The, I apply `overflow: auto` to `.item-panel`.  What this does is create a self-contained blow so that the widths of `.item_name` and `.item_type` are computed with respect to the width of the panel, not the top level container.  In your case, `.item_name` was taking 49% of the top level block, and thus pushing the `.item_type` block onto a second line, which is why it was jutting out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like since `item` has a width of 80%, and contains `icon` (75px wide) and `item_date` (100px wide), any time the window is squeezed there will be no room for `item_name` and `item_type`.

Try setting a `min-width` on `item` so that it doesn't totally collapse and leave no room for the inner divs:

```
.item {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 400px;
 }
```

You may also want to set a `min-width` and/or margins on your inner divs to keep them to the size you want.

Comment: I'm trying to get `item_name` and `item_type` to resize to whatever width it needs to resize to to make it fit. I'd rather not have a `min-width` on `.item`

Comment: By "fit", what do you mean?  "Use up all the space within" or "not get pushed to a new line"?

Comment: Use all the space within

Comment: Then see Marc Audet's answer. The width of the div containing your two inner divs is not constrained to the space between `icon` and `item_date`. `overflow:auto` will make it a block and thus constrain its width.